# How to fetch specific item first in template and then fetch other?

Tags: django, django-templates

In django template I am looping model on following way:

```
{% for image in image%}
{{image.image.url}}
{% endfor %}
```

Here I want to get the image where,

image model has **featured_image** Boolean option.
Here while looping, I want to loop the image which has **featured_image=True** first and then rest of the images.

How can I do this with single for loop?

Comment: You could order your objects my `featured_image` in your view `get_context_data` so you would have your `featured_image=True` first and `featured_image=False` after.

Comment: @JimP. is it possible with function based views too?
like :  image= ProductGallery.objects.filter(products=product).order_by(is_featured=True)

Comment: As long as you have access to the queryset, it does not matter if you have a class-based or function-based view. So yes, you should be able to do this in your function-based view.